# Add email attachment(s) from excel to outlook based on condition

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a list of names, email, attachment name and I need to send email and attach these attachment, my macro worked if I specify number of attachment, but what I have is not a fix number of attachments for each name/email, sometimes it's one and sometimes more than 1. Can you check my macro and advise what should I change/add in order to make the attachment dynamic?

```
Sub CreateNewMessage()

Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim obj As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim myDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Dim ToCc As Range, strBody, strSig As String
Dim fColorBlue, fColorGreen, fColorRed, fDukeBlue1, fDukeBlue2, fAggieMaroon, fAggieGray As String
Dim Greeting, emailContent As String
Dim emailOpen, emailMid1, emailMid2, emailMid3, emailClose, emailCustom, emailSig As String

Dim AttachmentPath, AttachmentNm As String

AttachmentPath = [O1] & "\"

fColorBlue = "#003846"
fColorGreen = "#5e9732"
fColorRed = "#FF0000"
fDukeBlue1 = "#001A57"
fDukeBlue2 = "#00009C"
fAggieMaroon = "#500000"
fAggieGray = "#332C2C"

For Each ToCc In ActiveSheet.[A2:A100] 'This is the range for how many records (rows) you want to send email

    '=============================================================
    Dim ToEmail, CcEmail, ToNm, CcNm, CcLNm As String
    Dim DescrDt, LocID, LsmID, DescrNm As String
    Dim Attach1, Attach2, Attach3 As String

    ToNm = Cells(ToCc.Row, [To___fName].Column).Value
    CcNm = Cells(ToCc.Row, [Cc___fName].Column).Value
    CcLNm = Cells(ToCc.Row, [Cc___LName].Column).Value
    ToEmail = Cells(ToCc.Row, [To___Email].Column).Value
    CcEmail = Cells(ToCc.Row, [Cc___Email].Column).Value
    Attach1 = Cells(ToCc.Row, [Attachment1].Column).Value
    Attach2 = Cells(ToCc.Row, [Attachment2].Column).Value
    Attach3 = Cells(ToCc.Row, [Attachment3].Column).Value


    AttachmentNm1 = Attach1
    AttachmentNm2 = Attach2
    AttachmentNm3 = Attach3

    Dim FileAttach1 As String
    Dim FileAttach2 As String
    Dim FileAttach3 As String

    FileAttach1 = AttachmentPath & AttachmentNm1
    FileAttach2 = AttachmentPath & AttachmentNm2
    FileAttach3 = AttachmentPath & AttachmentNm3
    'MsgBox FileAttach1
    'MsgBox FileAttach2
    'MsgBox FileAttach3

'Exit Sub

    '=============================================================

    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With aEmail
        '.SentOnBehalfOfName = "name@company.com"
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "name2@company.com"

        .To = ToEmail
        .cc = CcEmail '& "; " & SupvEmail & "; " & HREmail

        .Subject = "LSM Monthly Dashboard " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(ToNm) & Chr(32) & Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(DescrNm)
        '.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
        '.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        '.Importance = olImportanceHigh
        '.Sensitivity = olConfidential

        .HTMLBody = emailContent

        'MsgBox FileAttach1

        .Attachments.Add FileAttach1
        .Attachments.Add FileAttach2
        .Attachments.Add FileAttach3

        .display
        '   .send
    End With

NEXT_ToCC:
    Set aEmail = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set myDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
Next ToCc

End Sub
```

Comment: What determines who gets how many emails? Will need this info to make it dynamic

Comment: There's a column that counts number of attachments of each row, in this file it's column "M", but not sure how to build my condition, I'm a fresh to VBA

Comment: And where are the attachment locations? In columns? In one column as CSV?

Comment: Attachment location is in one location which is a folder in my documents but I placed the path in cell O1 as showing below: AttachmentPath = [O1] & "\". As for the files, they are PDF

Comment: And will you be attaching ever file that exists in the unique folder path? If so, just create a loop to reference every file in a given folder (which is documented on this site already) and attach the files as you loop

Comment: yes, I will be attaching all the files that are saved in this folder as long as they meet the criteria that I set in the macro. Can you share the link of this loop? I'm still new to VBA coding

Comment: There are a couple of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba). You will take your value in `O1` and use that as the folder location. You can then loop through all files and attach them to your email 1 by 1. The loops utilized in the folder when stop once all files have been looped through.

Comment: I would review that. Take a shot at it and come back with the relevant code when you are done. Most of the code you shared is not related to your problem. Only ask people to review the code that needs fixing and you are more likely to get better help

Comment: can you post example of you excel file?

Answer (score 0):

You should use array to do this.

Add files paths to an array.

Dim files()
Files = array(path1, path2)

And after ‚htmlbody’ write:

For i = lbound(files) to ubound(files)
    .attachments.add files(i)

Next i